# Problem with Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls

Tags: web-applications

I'm troubleshooting some old code that uses the Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls dll to create tree views and tabstrip controls on some pages. The tabstrip controls are not behaving correctly on our test site. Instead of hiding the portions of the page that are not on the selected tab they show everything. This error doesn't happen when I run the project locally on my computer. I assume there is some kind of configuration difference that I'm not aware of that causes the problem. Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the web controls are not installed properly on the server.   I believe you will need to run the .msi or installation package to properly install them .   Make sure they're in the GAC while you're at it (or in the /bin directory), and all that other good stuff.

Comment: They are in the /bin directory of the website (ASP.NET) is that not good enough? They must be in the GAC?

Comment: No, the installer will install other files into some miscellaneous directories of the server I believe.

Comment: This blog posthttp://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/02/21/70219.aspx
describes some steps for getting the web controls to work with asp.net 2.0 - it involves making some settings to the corresponding web.config, which I could imagine emulate steps otherwise performed by an installer.